# Dynamically naming component from a config file in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-component

Seen lots of answers to this and for some reason just don't get it, or it doesn't work in this instance. I've currently built my router to dynamically build routes based on a config file i'm importing. The issue i'm having is, i also want the component the route renders to come from the config file but can't get it to work.

```
export const configNavOptions = {
config:[
{
  group: "general",
  paths: [
    {name:"name 1", component:"Component 1"},
    {name:"name 2", component:"Component 2"},
    {name:"name 3", component:"Component 3"},
  ]
}
]
}

AND THEN WITHIN MY ROUTER I AM MAPPING THE CONFIG FILE AS SO

  <Switch>
      {configNavOptions.config.map(config => (
          config.paths.map(path => (
            <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.url}/${config.group}/${path.name}`}
            component={path.component}/>
          ))
        ))}
        </Switch>
```

If i replace the {path.component} with an actual component, it works perfectly, i just can't get this last step..

Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365

Answer (score 0):

i fix this problen in my case i have this:

```
 <Root>
    <PopNotification />
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader siteLoader />}>
          <Switch>
            {
              allRoutes()[this.props.userKind].map(singleRoute => {
                return <Route {...singleRoute} />;
              })
            }
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </Root>
```

where this.props.userkind is the kind of the user  and allRoutes function looks like that:

```
    export function allRoutes(){


    return {

[userRoles.bufet_owner]: [
        ...publicRoutesArray,
        ...commonPrivateRoutes,
        {
            exact: true,
            path: '/plan',
            key: "PlanBody",
            component: <PlanBody />,
        },
        {
            exact: true,
            path: '/success-plan',
            key: "PlanSuccess",
            component:<PlanSuccess />,
        },
        {
            exact: true,
            path: [
                '/accounts/entry',
                '/accounts/egress',
                '/accounts/entry/:page',
                '/accounts/egress/:page',
            ],
            component: AccountsContainer,
            key: 'AccountsContainer'
        },
}

    }
```

i hope this help you to fix your problem